# simple mailing list

Tags: java, php, email, list, subscribe

Can anybody give me details on what to code into a page?

Basically i am required to build a mailing list from scratch where people can subscribe and they are added to a mailing list.

What would be the php/javascript behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mailing list is quite simple. You'd need to decide how you'd want to do it, but in general, you'd have a subscribe page and a post page. I am not testing this code, so it may contain flaws, but it should give you an idea of a flat-file based mailing list.

In practical implementations, you should use MySQL, validate and confirm e-mails, check for errors and so on. Also, don't forget that this does not authenticate the post page. You ideally need strong authentication to ensure your mailing list isn't compromised. Additionally know that you -must- have an unsubscribe feature - this will be easier with MySQL than with flat-file.

### subscribe.php

```
<?php
// Has the form been posted?
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
  // Append the submitted e-mail to the list.
  $file = fopen('list.txt', 'a');
  fputs($file, $_POST['email'] . "\n");
  fclose($file);

  // Send a message to the browser.
  die('Added to mailing list.');
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Subscribe to Mailing List</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="email" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

### post.php

```
<?php
// Has the form been submitted?
if(isset($_POST['body']))
{
  // This should load the file into $lines, as an array of, well, lines.
  $lines = file('list.txt');

  // For each line, send a message. $line should contain an e-mail address.
  foreach($lines as $line)
    mail($line, $_POST['subject'], $_POST['body']);

  // Send a message to the browser.
  die("Message delivered.");
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Post to Mailing List</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Post</h1>
  <form action="#" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="subject" /><br/>
   <textarea name="body"></textarea><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: much appreciated. i appreciate showing the base of it. i should be able to get it going once i read up and play with it on my test server. I just needed a bit of clarification as im under a big workload at the moment lol im guessing you mean that users emails can be hijacked and are insecure without authentication basically

Comment: Well, if the post page is unprotected and gets discovered, it can be used to send mass SPAM, which is always dangerous. Also, this example uses flat-file, which you should modify to use MySQL instead.

Comment: Just commenting to say I have fixed the code so that it will actually run properly, but please remember that this is only a very simple example and shouldn't be used for production purposes.

Comment: cheers bud. appreciate ur time to give some advice. i should make another question soon about some sites that developers sorta go to discuss things so i can read some previous posts and study a bit

Answer (score 0):

There's actually more behind it - more MySQL. You'll need MySQL, PHP and Javascript (for UI and client-side validation)

Where do you want to began?

**Simple Model:**
User -> inputs email -> validated via javascript -> if (true) -> submits via POST/GET -> validates PHP -> if (true) -> goes into MySQL database.

Comment: yer i shoulda known id need a database, i mean where else are the values gonna be stored. cheers for the flow diagram

Comment: sorry i reread post. i normally just modify php etc. I have no real background in mysql, php or javascript although my dad might be able to help with mysql. I know how to use databases just not much about writing the code from scratch.

Comment: ill most likely get some books and start reading heavily lol. i dont really have contacts in my region that can advise me on any elements of coding